# Can't upgrade from MVC2 to MVC3

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-2

I've got myself an MVC2 web applicatin using .NET Framework 4 and am following [these](http://www.asp.net/whitepapers/mvc3-release-notes#upgrading) instructions to the T. However at step 10 when I save the updated *ProjectTypeGuids* I get a message saying **"The project file  *projectname*.csproj cannot be opened. The project type is not supported by this installation."**

I do have MVC3 installed and am running VS2010, so I don't know what could the going wrong. Anyone have any thoughts on the matter? Thanks!

EDIT:

For what it's worth. If I create a blank project from scratch, I have the ability to create a new MVC3 project. However, if I right click on my solution and click *add*->*New Project...* I can only add MVC2 projects. This leads me to think that the solution is configured somehow to only support MVC2, however I can't figure out how to change it.

Comment: What IDE are you using? Do you have VWD or the full version of Visual Studio?

Comment: I'm using VS2010 Professional full version.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is an extra package which is [ASP.NET MVC 3 Tools Update](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=1491), you must download and install it too.

Solution 1:

Open the visual Studio Find In Files Dialog and Select your project folder, then search for old GUID and replace it with new one exactly. Backup the directory before doing this.
Actually You must select the whole solution folder and search all the files not a specific extension.

Solution 2:
You must take a careful look at your csproj and sln files and compare it with a working one on your system to find the difference. if you have file compare tools like winmerge, use it to compare files character by character

Comment: I have this installed as well. I tried installing it anyway and got "Microsoft ASP.NET MVC 3 Tools Update does not apply"

Comment: Create a New MVC3 Project from Visual Studio Menu, open the .csproj file and copy and paste that GUID to your .csproj file.

Comment: It's the exact same GUID so I get the same result. For some reason the new MVC3 Project is able to work with that GUID, but my existing project(s) can't. My existing project is inside a solution with several other projects...would all of the projects in the solution be required to have the same GUID?

Comment: If all of them are MVC 3 Projects , yes but if they are different projects like Class Library or etc, then no. Take a look at .sln file and check it, maybe you find the old guid there. Open it with a text editor like notepad.

Comment: Yes, I need them all to be MVC3 Projects, but I still can't switch them to MVC3 Projects because it won't let me change the GUID on any of them.

Comment: Why, I can't understand why you can't change the GUID. Did you looked at .sln file?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/20356/discussion-between-jani-and-hemlocker)